# ClassCastException in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to catch an exception and return a value to my client page, but I get `ClassCastException` and it is not returning any value.

My code snippet-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/config/MyFile/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Myfile> getAllFlatFileTrafficCops()
{
    try
    {
        return MyFileServices.getAlldata();
    }
    catch (final ResourceAccessException r)
    {
        final Throwable flatfileTrafficCopStatus;
        flatfileTrafficCopStatus = r.getCause();

        return (List<FlatFileTrafficCop>) flatfileTrafficCopStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: r.getCause() returns Throwable and you can't cast it to a List.

Comment: If you're getting a class-cast exception it's pretty clear what's the problem. the `Throwable flatfileTrafficCopStatus` is not castable to `List<FlatFileTrafficCop>`!

Comment: How does that even compile? Your method returns `List<Myfile>`, but you are trying to return `List<FlatFileTrafficCop>` in the catch clause.

Comment: That i agree.. in that case what i need to do? i am pretty new to spring

Comment: No No.. that was by mistake i edited before pasting my question here

Comment: even i tried using responseentity but same casting problem..

Comment: If you get this exception you can return an empty list Collections.emptyList() and log the exception.

Comment: HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("server unreachable", "404");
        return (List<FlatFileTrafficCop>) new ResponseEntity<List>(responseHeaders, HttpStatus.METHOD_FAILURE);

Comment: Try reading this article: https://dzone.com/articles/exception-handling-spring-rest

Answer (score 0):

All you can do in this case in `Exception` situation catch the exception and encapsulate it in your meaningful custom exception and propagate it back to caller function and for web display meaningful error text.

Always propagate exceptions back to caller. For debug you might want to add a `log` statement over there.

```
catch (final ResourceAccessException r)
    {
        CustomException cException = new CustomException(r);
        throw cException;
        //OR
        FlatFileTrafficCop emptyObj= new FlatFileTrafficCop(Witherr);
        //add that in a list and return
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first is `ClassCastException` child of `ResourceAccessException`? No, so your catch will not work, if you want to catch `ClassCastException` you have to make 2nd catch for it

```
catch (final ClassCastException e){}
```

but while you are using spring no need to catch it like this you can use [@ExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) instead